# Getting U+fffd/65533 instead of special character from Query String

Tags: c#, .net, flash, encoding, url-encoding

I have a C# .net web project that have a globalization tag set to:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="nb-no" uiCulture="no"/>
```

When this URL a Flash application (you get the same problem when you enter the URL manually in a browser): c_product_search.aspx?search=kjøkken (alternatively: c_product_search-aspx?search=kj%F8kken

Both return the following character codes:

```
k U+006b 107
j U+006a 106
� U+fffd 65533
k U+006b 107
k U+006b 107
e U+0065 101
n U+006e 110
```

I don't know too much about character encoding, but it seems that the ø has been given a unicode replacement character, right?

I tried to change the globalization tag to:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="nb-no" uiCulture="no"/>
```

That made the request work. However, now, other searches on my page stopped working.

I also tried the following with similar results:

```
NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
string search = (string)qs["search"];
```

What should I do?

Kind Regards,

nitech

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the combination Firefox/Asp.Net. When you manually entered a URL in Firefox's address bar, if the url contains french or swedish characters, Firefox will encode the url with "ISO-8859-1" by default.

But when asp.net recieves such a url, it thinks that it's utf-8 encoded ... And encoded characters become "U+fffd". I couldn't find a way in asp.net to detect that the url is "ISO-8859-1". Request.Encoding is set to utf-8 ... :(

Several solutions exist :

- put `<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>` in your Web.config. But your may comme with other problems, and your application won't be standard anymore (it will not work with languages like japanese) ... And anyway, I prefer using UTF-8 !
- go to about:config in Firefox and set the value of `network.standard-url.encode-query-utf8` to true. It will now work for you (Firefox will encode all your url with utf-8). But not for anybody else ...
- The least worst solution I could come with was to handle this with code. If the default decoding didn't work, we reparse QueryString with iso8859-1 :

  ```
  string query = Request.QueryString["search"];
  if (query.Contains("%ufffd"))
      query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))["search"];
  query = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(query);
  ```

It works with hyperlinks and manually-entered url, in french, english, or japanese. But I don't know how it will handle other encodings like ISO8859-5 (russian) ...

Does anyone have a better solution ?

This solves only the problem of manually-entered url. In your hyperlinks, don't forget to encode url parameters with HttpUtility.UrlEncode on the server, or encodeURIComponent on the javascript code. And use HttpUtility.UrlDecode to decode it.

Comment: Thanks. If you look at the bottom - that solution worked for me. I was not able to change the encoding inside the cs-code. I had to do it before the session was initiated - inside global.asax. But perhaps your solution is working because it does not try to change the encoding of the HTTPContext.

Comment: Just to close this question. Both mine and this and probably other answers on this page will help you along. It's been a year since I did any AS-coding, so I never got to test this properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public string GetEncodedQueryString(string key)
    {
        string query = Request.QueryString[key];
        if (query != null)
            if (query.Contains((char)0xfffd))
                query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))[key];
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. The project is so old now that I have no current chance to test it. Maybe someone else tried this and found it a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is in the flash, not the .net.
it sends the special character in a weird way.
try to urlencode the search string bevore you send it to the server.

Comment: Well. In flash there is a function called escape. I've tried this and it makes no difference. 

Also, I get the same problem if I simply write the url in to the address field manually.

Comment: what we do on our site, is that we have, depending on the clients language, the dedicated ISO encoding in request & response. because many of the clients do not understand UTF-16. that would also be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is expecting the URL-encoded request to be based on UTF-8, the character "`ø`" should be "`%C3%B8`", not "`%F8`".  Whatever function you're using to escape/encode that request, you probably need to pass it the name of the underlying character encoding, "UTF-8".

Comment: You're onto something there. It seems there is a variation on URL-encoding between AS2 and AS3. I made a sample on AS2 that works fine, but apparently the same sample encodes differently on AS3. 

This post tells more about this. It does however not provide a solution. 
http://www.ultrashock.com/forums/actionscript/as3-escape-vs-as2-escape-122046.html

Comment: And also, it doesn't make sense that I decode ø to U+fffd if the ultrashock forum is correct when it says AS3 encode with ISO-8859-1.

Comment: If your .NET backend is expecting the URL-encoded form to be based on UTF-8, it will see %F8 as an error and replace it with the standard replacement character, U+FFFD. What happens if you manually enter the string its UTF-8 form, "kj%C3%B8kken"?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that ActionScript 2.0 will send the URL encoded/escaped with UTF-8 while ActionScript 3.0 used ISO-8859-1. The way to solve this was to change the Request.Encoding value inside Global.asax if an encoding is specified in the URL:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    // encoding specified?
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["encoding"]))
    {
        ctx.Request.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(ctx.Request["encoding"]);
    }        
}
```

Could it be done differently?

Regards,
nitech